# SQL Server- Inserting into multople selects?

Tags: sql-server

I have about 100 select statements that look like this:

```
select * from users where clientid='GUID'

select * from providers where clientid='GUID'
```

They are really simple, but how I can I define the GUID once instead of having to put it into each select statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @GuidVar VARCHAR(38);
SELECT @GuidVar ='GUID'
select * from users where clientid=@GuidVar
select * from providers where clientid=@GuidVar
```

Comment: why not declare `@GuidVar` as `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER`??

Comment: No specific philosophy behind it. Was just worried that clientid is of data type varchar.

Answer (score 1):

use the `IN` clause and just put a list of comma separated IDs

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE clientid IN (guid1,guid2,guid3)
```

[MySQL IN Clause](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-in-clause.htm)

Comment: You answer does not address the question, please read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this might help you:

```
select * from users u
inner join providers p
on p.clientid = u.clientid 
where u.clientid = 'GUID'
```

And you can continue to add inner joins for all tables and join on clientid. You will only require one where clause at the end.

The downside is that you will get all the columns in on row for each table. What you can do is to select specify tables or columns e.g `select u.*, p.clientid`